# Pika/RabbitMQ how to create new channel from single connection?

Tags: pika

I have a method with python pica. Here the consumer needs to create a channel for each queue. I get an error when I write this code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9UTb.png)

```
def Process(channel, exc, que):
    channel.exchange_declare(exchange=exc, exchange_type='direct', durable=True)
    result = channel.queue_declare(durable=True, queue=que, auto_delete=False,exclusive=False )

    def callback_rabbit(ch,method,properties,body):
        print("Message received = ", body)

    channel.queue_bind(exchange=exc, queue=que, routing_key=que)
    channel.basic_consume(on_message_callback=callback_rabbit,queue=que, auto_ack=True)
    channel.start_consuming()

def Start():        
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('guest','guest')
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('127.0.0.1','5672','/',credentials))

    items = {"exc":[{"exchangeName":"bam", "queueName":"bam_queue1"},{"exchangeName":"bam", "queueName":"bam_queue2"},{"exchangeName":"bam", "queueName":"bam_queue3"}]}
    for item in items["exc"]:
        channel = connection.channel()
        t_msg = Thread(target=Process, args=(channel,item["exchangeName"],item["queueName"]))
        t_msg.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pika is not thread safe. You should create a new connection and channel in your `Process` method.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand.
There are 30 queues in the exchange. Do I need to create a new connection for each queue?  Can you show me an example?

Comment: Yes, using 30 connections (one per thread) is one solution and is probably the easiest-to-implement solution in your case.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/8CRFGxwy-os/discussion

Comment: Isn't every connection system tired? Doesn't every connection system use the CPU more?

Comment: Don't worry about that. Your main concern at this point should be producing correct code that works with Pika.