# RabbitMQ pika: cannot stop consuming a stream queue because it doesn't allow nack or reject

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

My application has a [Stream](https://www.rabbitmq.com/streams.html) queue and I want it to stop consuming when a certain condition is met. Since [start_consuming](https://start_consuming()) blocks forever with a `BlockingConnection`, it looks like the only way to get out is to call [stop_consuming](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/adapters/blocking.html#pika.adapters.blocking_connection.BlockingChannel.stop_consuming) somewhere in a callback.

Unfortunately, that doesn't work because `stop_consuming` will reject all pending messages (from pika docs)

> NOTE: pending non-ackable messages will be lost; pending ackable messages will be rejected.

...and you can't do a reject on a stream queue as this error message confirms:

`operation basic.reject caused a connection exception not_implemented: "basic.nack and basic.reject not supported by stream queues queue 'stream-queue' in vhost '/'"`

Here's a minimal example. Server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost')
)
channel_stream = connection.channel()

channel_stream.queue_declare(
    "stream-queue",
    auto_delete=False, exclusive=False, durable=True,
    arguments={
        'x-queue-type': 'stream',
    }
)
channel_stream.basic_qos(
    prefetch_count=1,
)


class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        channel_stream.basic_consume(
            queue="stream-queue",
            on_message_callback=self.stream_callback,
        )

    def stream_callback(self, channel, method, props, body):
        print(f"received '{body.decode()}' via {method.routing_key}")
        channel_stream.stop_consuming()


server = Server()

try:
    channel_stream.start_consuming()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    connection.close()
```

And the client code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost')
)
channel_stream = connection.channel()

channel_stream.queue_declare(
    "stream-queue",
    durable=True,
    arguments={
        'x-queue-type': 'stream',
    }
)

# This publishes twice: once to trigger the server's callback
# and again to get a message in the queue that the server is forced
# to nack, causing a crash. 
for i in range(2):
    channel_stream.basic_publish(
        exchange='',
        routing_key='stream-queue',
        body=f"stream data".encode()
    )
connection.close()
```

And the full output:

```
~/anaconda3/envs/py310/bin/python ~/workspace/rabbitmq_train/stream_bug/server_stream_only.py 
received 'stream data' via stream-queue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/workspace/rabbitmq_train/stream_bug/server_stream_only.py", line 36, in <module>
    channel_stream.start_consuming()
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1880, in start_consuming
    self._process_data_events(time_limit=None)
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2041, in _process_data_events
    self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=time_limit)
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 848, in process_data_events
    self._dispatch_channel_events()
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 567, in _dispatch_channel_events
    impl_channel._get_cookie()._dispatch_events()
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1507, in _dispatch_events
    consumer_info.on_message_callback(self, evt.method,
  File "~/workspace/rabbitmq_train/stream_bug/server_stream_only.py", line 30, in stream_callback
    channel_stream.stop_consuming()
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1893, in stop_consuming
    self._cancel_all_consumers()
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1494, in _cancel_all_consumers
    self.basic_cancel(consumer_tag)
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1802, in basic_cancel
    self._flush_output(
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1350, in _flush_output
    self._connection._flush_output(lambda: self.is_closed, *waiters)
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 523, in _flush_output
    raise self._closed_result.value.error
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosedByBroker: (540, "NOT_IMPLEMENTED - basic.nack and basic.reject not supported by stream queues queue 'stream-queue' in vhost '/'")

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And this is how I started the server:

```
docker run -it --rm -d --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Comment: Hey, you're on a roll. Gabriele is a co-worker of mine, and his suggestion is a good one, though I'm not 100% sure it'll solve your problem. Pika likes to do some magic behind the scenes as you've found. If you don't mind, open an issue in the Pika repository and we can figure out the best solution there (https://github.com/pika/pika/issues). The way you have been reporting issues is *excellent*, please keep up the good work.

Comment: Sounds good, looks like he reported it already: https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/1389

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same `channel` for different kinds of queues.
In general, it is not a best practise. You should have a channel per consumer.

To solve your problem:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost')
)
channel = connection.channel()
channelStream = connection.channel()

channelStream.queue_declare(
    "stream-queue",
    auto_delete=False, exclusive=False, durable=True,
    arguments={
        'x-queue-type': 'stream',
    }
)
channel.queue_declare(
    "normal-queue"
)
channelStream.basic_qos(
    prefetch_count=1,
)


class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        channelStream.basic_consume(
            queue="stream-queue",
            on_message_callback=self.stream_callback,
        )
        channel.basic_consume(
            queue="normal-queue",
            on_message_callback=self.normal_callback,
        )

    def stream_callback(self, channel, method, props, body):
        print(f"received '{body}' via {method.routing_key}")
        channelStream.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
        channelStream.stop_consuming()

    def normal_callback(self, channel, method, props, body):
        print(f"received '{body}' via {method.routing_key}")
        channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
        channel.stop_consuming()


server = Server()

try:
    channel.start_consuming()
    channelStream.start_consuming()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    connection.close()
```

Multi-Thread would be:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import threading

import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost')
)

connectionStream = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost')
)
channel = connection.channel()
channelStream = connectionStream.channel()

channelStream.queue_declare(
    "stream-queue",
    auto_delete=False, exclusive=False, durable=True,
    arguments={
        'x-queue-type': 'stream',
    }
)
channel.queue_declare(
    "normal-queue"
)
channelStream.basic_qos(
    prefetch_count=1,
)


class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def stream_callback(self, channel, method, props, body):
        print(f"stream_callback '{body}' via {method.routing_key}")
        channelStream.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
        channelStream.stop_consuming()

    def normal_callback(self, channel, method, props, body):
        print(f"normal_callback '{body}' via {method.routing_key}")
        channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
        channel.stop_consuming()

    def start_consume_normal(self):
        print(f"start_consume_normal ")
        channel.basic_consume(
            queue="normal-queue",
            on_message_callback=self.normal_callback,
        )
        channel.start_consuming()

    def start_consume_stream(self):
        channelStream.basic_consume(
            queue="stream-queue",
            on_message_callback=self.stream_callback,
        )
        print(f"start_consume_stream ")
        channelStream.start_consuming()


server = Server()

try:
    x = threading.Thread(target=server.start_consume_normal, args=())
    x.start()
    print(f"start_consume_normal")
    x2 = threading.Thread(target=server.start_consume_stream, args=())
    x2.start()
    print(f"start_consume_stream")
    input()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    connection.close()
```

[Note about multi-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58504857/pika-rabbitmq-how-to-create-new-channel-from-single-connection)

Comment: I think this works based on an initial test. One question: doesn't `start_consuming` block? How is`channelStream.start_consuming()` able to run when it's blocked by the previous line?

Comment: That was a pseudo solution. btw added a multi-thread solution. Please read about Pika and multi-threads

Comment: Weirdly the previous solution worked, despite blocking the 2nd line the callbacks for both still run.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid threads as much as possible: I like `BlockingConnection` because I can handle all business logic through callbacks. It looks like `SelectConnection` can meet my needs: there's one ioloop for an arbitrary number of channels.

Comment: The only drawback to `SelectConnection` is the catch-all behavior, hence my other SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73736444/17404810

Comment: I am not a python expert, but in general, the main point is that you have to use two different channels. 
You can't use the same channel to consume two queues. It is not a best practice.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work anyway. I added an even simpler example using only 1 channel and 1 stream queue.

Comment: you are right, I can reproduce the issue